# jQuery filter through range of text and apply a new bg color

Tags: jquery

I want to use jquery to search for a text range in the .sos cell and change the bg color based on the value of the range set. By range i mean a singular instance of each # 1-6 , would be if text contains the number 1 , 2 , 3, 4 ,5 or 6 exactly.

```
text value 1-6 = green
text value 7-12 = blue
text value 13-20 = yellow
text value 21-26 = pink
text value 21-26 = black
then also if no text value matched set a different color or purple
```

example html

```
<td class="sos">11</td>
<td class="sos">2</td>
<td class="sos">32</td>
<td class="sos">3</td>
```

I know how to do each text value 1 at a time , but haven't seen any tuts to do a range , if possible.

```
$('.sos').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == '3') {
        $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "range"? Please give an example.

Comment: i gave the range above , if td.sos contains text 1-6 (1,2,3,4,5 or 6) , then apply a bg color of green

Comment: $('.sos').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() >= 2 && $(this).text() <= 7) {
            $(this).css('background', 'red');
        }
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign `ID` to your `HTML Table` and there is no need to assign class to each `td`:

**HTML**

```
<table id="tableID">
 <tr>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>32</td>
   <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

AND **Jquery**:

```
$("#tableID td").each(function() {
   var a = $(this).text();
   if(parseInt(a)>=1 && parseInt(a)<=6 )
   {
     $(this).css('background', 'red');
   }
   //... AND so on for other conditions
});
```

OR

```
$("#tableID td").each(function() {     
   (parseInt( $(this).text() ) >= 1 && parseInt( $(this).text() ) <= 6 ?
    $(this).css('background', 'red') : "") 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cy7ydx0L/)